# Looking for references to study $U^p$ and $V^p$ spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, hyperbolic-pde

I am studying some papers in the analysis of nonlinear PDEs and I am encountering the $U^p$ and $V^p$ spaces for the first time. Where can I find references more detailed than papers?

**Edited**

The spaces I mentioned above are defined in section two of this paper:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.2011.pdf.

Comment: Hi Ali, could you add a sample of the references you are studying? Such symbols do not seem to have a standard meaning, and should be considered in their context.

Comment: Thank you @DanieleTampieri. I put more details about the spaces I asked about, they are defined in section two of this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0708.2011.pdf

Comment: You can take a look to Chapter 3 of this PhD thesis https://publikationen.bibliothek.kit.edu/1000100707 for a good introduction.

Comment: @RaffaeleScandone I think you should also make that an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take a look at Herbert Koch's contribution in

*Koch, Herbert; Tataru, Daniel; Vişan, Monica*, [**Dispersive equations and nonlinear waves. Generalized Korteweg-de Vries, nonlinear Schrödinger, wave and Schrödinger maps**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-0348-0736-4), Oberwolfach Seminars 45. Basel: Birkhäuser/Springer (ISBN 978-3-0348-0735-7/pbk; 978-3-0348-0736-4/ebook). xii, 312 p. (2014). [ZBL1304.35003](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1304.35003).

Chapter 4 of Koch's notes there is specifically concerning the $U^p$ and $V^p$ spaces.

You should note that these notes are from 2014, and so there are a few newer developments covered in the PhD thesis mentioned in [Raffaele Scandone's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/419075/looking-for-references-to-study-up-and-vp-spaces#comment1076145_419075) that are not included in this discussion. Though for reaching the paper you linked to certainly the material in the book should be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Here is [one fairly recent paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02066) of Sebastian Herr (the second author in the paper you linked) and Timothy Candy in which they use $U^p$ and $V^p$ spaces. During a [winter school in Obergurgl in 2022](https://www.uibk.ac.at/mathematik/summerschool2022/), Herr said that paper is a good reference for the $U^p-V^p$ spaces. It is probably worth having a look, although in that case they use the spaces for a nonlinear wave equation, which makes things not that simple as it is of second order in time (unlike the KP-II equation). That is why you will find two distinct adapted function spaces, $U^2_{\pm}$.

The book mentioned by Willie Wong was very helpul to me as it takes the time to explain things in detail; I almost didn't look at the original paper by Hadac, Herr, Koch as the main argument is all contained in that book. I didn't know of [this PhD thesis](https://publikationen.bibliothek.kit.edu/1000100707) from Scandone's comment, it seems it is quite a valid reference which confronts all the previous ones (it also mention the paper of Candy and Herr).

**Edit:**

A list of all the references I know:

- [Koch, Tataru - 2005](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401234) (The first published paper which uses these spaces; very technical)
- [Koch, Tataru - 2007](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0612717) (A priori bounds for the 1D cubic NLS in negative Sobolev spaces; I have seen there are nice heuristics in the explanation of the spaces)
- [Hadac, Herr, Koch - 2009](https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.2011) (Well... the paper on the KP-II equation; historically, it's the first nonlinear problem in which it seems that the $X^{s,b}$ spaces by Bourgain do not work and the use of $U^p-V^p$ seems somewhat necessary)
- [Koch, Tataru, Visan - 2014](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-0348-0736-4) (The book; a very nice introductory reference which compares several models; see the first part (Koch's notes); contains most of the arguments from the paper on the KP-II equation in a simplified way)
- [Koch, Tataru - 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.02534) (Very detailed (see appendix B), maybe a bit technical; a bit more recent than the book)
- [Candy, Herr - 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.02066) (On the division problem for the Wave maps equation; very well-written and understandable)
- [PhD thesis of Andreas Geyer-Schulz - 2019](https://publikationen.bibliothek.kit.edu/1000100707) (It seems a good and detailed reference which compares the previous ones)

There are surely many other papers that make use of these spaces. I think it is worth having a look at most of the above ones.